# Print tensor value tensorflow 2.4

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tied to print one value while i train my Transformer.

```py
@tf.function
def train_step(inp, tar):
    tar_inp = tar[:, :-1]
    tar_real = tar[:, 1:]
    global i
    if i == 1:
      print('__________________')
      tf.print('Inp: ', inp, output_stream=sys.stdout)
      tf.print('Tar: ', tar, output_stream=sys.stdout)
      tf.print('Tar_inp: ', tar_inp, output_stream=sys.stdout)
      tf.print('Tar_real: ', tar_real, output_stream=sys.stdout)
      i += 1
    .......
```

But `tf.print` doesn't print anything. However my first `print('_')` works
What did I do wrong? Pls, help me to print my tensors.

**UPDATE**:
U also could explain to me the structure of `tar_inp` and `tar_real` instead of fixing `tf. print`.

Comment: When you use `print(inp)` does it still print?

Comment: @yudhiesh, Yes, but i see tensor class, not its value

Comment: Include the output.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing it to `print()` with `tensor.numpy()` -

```
@tf.function
def train_step(inp, tar):
    tar_inp = tar[:, :-1]
    tar_real = tar[:, 1:]
    global i
    if i == 1:
      print('__________________')
      print('Inp: ', inp.numpy())
      print('Tar: ', tar.numpy())
      print('Tar_inp: ', tar_inp.numpy())
      print('Tar_real: ', tar_real.numpy())
      i += 1
```

---

W.r.t the `tar_inp` and `tar_real`, indexing works the same way on tensors as it does on numpy arrays but it returns a tensor object. So you can index, and then convert pull the values as a numpy array later.

```
print(tf.convert_to_tensor([1,2,3]).numpy()) #get numpy
print(tf.convert_to_tensor([1,2,3])[1:].numpy()) #get numpy after indexing
print(tf.convert_to_tensor([1,2,3]).numpy()[1:]) #index after getting numpy
```

```
[1 2 3]
[2 3]
[2 3]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: can you print one of the tensors? that is not possible

Comment: I printed these values(tar_inp and tar_real) but i don't understand these values and how they refer to my transformer. inp is long text, tar the same text but shorter. I don't understand training part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eval`](http://tensorflow.biotecan.com/python/Python_1.8/tensorflow.google.cn/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/eval.html) from `tf.keras.backend`.

Simple example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tf.keras.backend as K

x = tf.constant([3.,3.])
print(x)
print(K.eval(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
model.compile(... run_eagerly=True)
```

Then everything will work fine. You may have to remove `@tf.function` (let me know if it's the case).

The reason is that Tensorflow is made to be used with edge devices and/or anything outside of Python. When writing Tensorflow code, you're creating a graph that will be executed independent of Python. If you want it to be executed as Python functions, for instance if you want to print the values within Python, you will need to execute eagerly.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for (batch, (inp, tar)) in enumerate(dataset):
    tar_inp = tar[:, :-1]
    tar_real = tar[:, 1:]
    print(tar_inp, tar_real, sep='\n\n')
    break
```

```
[[    2    90 21617 ...     0     0     0]
 [    2   282  1103 ...     0     0     0]
 [    2  1120 20666 ...     0     0     0]
 ...
 [    2   637    19 ...     0     0     0]
 [    2   200  6206 ...     0     0     0]
 [    2   647    19 ...     0     0     0]], shape=(64, 74), dtype=int32)

tf.Tensor(
[[   90 21617   130 ...     0     0     0]
 [  282  1103  1514 ...     0     0     0]
 [ 1120 20666  4508 ...     0     0     0]
 ...
 [  637    19  1789 ...     0     0     0]
 [  200  6206  9124 ...     0     0     0]
 [  647    19  1487 ...     0     0     0]], shape=(64, 74), dtype=int32)
```